# Array is out of bounds while counting [CORRECT]

Tags: java, arrays, printing, indexoutofboundsexception

I need to print an array that contains duplicate words. I already have my array working but I cannot figure out how to count the words properly. I already know that when my index counter (i) is at 49, and when (i) wants to count to 50, I get the error but I don't know any other way to adjust my method to work. Can you please help me? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

This is my array:

blue blue blue blue blue blue blue blue blue blue blue blue blue brown green 
green green green green green green green lemon lemon lemon lemon lemon lemon lilac lilac 
orange orange red red red red red red red red red red white white white 
white white yellow yellow yellow

***CORRECTED CODE***

```
public static void printWordCount(String[] z) 
{
    System.out.println("THERE ARE " + wordTotal + " WORDS IN THE FILE");
    System.out.println("WORD W/ COUNT:");

    int i = 0;
    int count = 0;

    while(i < z.length - 1) {
        if (z[i].equalsIgnoreCase(z[i+1])) {
            i++;
            count++;
        }
        else if (!z[i].equalsIgnoreCase(z[i+1]) || i == z.length - 1) {
            count++;
            System.out.println(z[i] + " / " + count);
            i++;
            count = 0;
        }
    }
    count++;
    System.out.println(z[i] + " / " + count);
}
```

This is my output:

THERE ARE 50 WORDS IN THE FILE

WORD W/ COUNT:

blue / 13

brown / 1

green / 8

lemon / 6

lilac / 2

orange / 2

red / 10

white / 5

yellow / 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your condition allows `i` to reach `z.length - 1`.
Then `z[i].equalsIgnoreCase(z[i+1])` brings you out of the array bounds, since `i+1 == z.length`.

If you wish to compare the `i`th elements to the `i+1`th element, change the condition to :

```
while(i < z.length - 1)
```

Then you should probably add **after** the loop :

```
        count++;
        System.out.println(z[i] + " / " + count);
```

to print the number of occurences of the final word.

Comment: always ahead of me on these answers :)

Comment: Thank you for helping! However, I changed it but it still doesn't print the last set of words. I'll update my question with the most recent code.

Comment: @Braulio See my edit. Haven't tested it, but something like it should work.

Comment: @Eran! Thank you I got it. You were right! I played with my code more, and got it. Thanks a bunch & take care my friend!